# Highlight certain text in a PyGTK TextView

Tags: python, pygtk

I have TextView with pages of text, but I want to be able to highlight (change the background color) of specific strings in different colors. Is this possible? If so, can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried this myself, but [TextBuffer.insert_with_tags](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html#method-gtktextbuffer--insert-with-tags) with a properly configured [TextTag](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktexttag.html) looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

If the specific strings are always the same, as in a programming language, then use `GtkSourceView` instead.